# How to scale redis using docker compose, and each redis own its volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to have 50 instance of redis, can I achieve this using docker-compose ? or should I use Kuberneties instead ? the point here is I want each instance has its own port and its own volume.

another question is how I can distribute the instances between multiple hosts, for example each 10 container will be host it on different server. (docker-swarm or Kuberneties ?)

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes would fit your use case. I would use the Helm chart from the stable:

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/redis/6.4.0

Invest some time in the kubernetes as then you get so much for free. Redis would be a Statefulset in Kubernetes and you can scale it as you like if you have the resources.
In many cloud providers Redis should be an out of the box Application:

A statefulset garantees that each instance uses its own data volume.

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/redis/how-to/create/

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have setup the Kubernetes, now I have master, and 2 node which the joined the cluster, I have checked the Helm chart for redis, it suppor 2 type of redis, 

type 1: Redis. (Supports multiple databases)
type 2: Redis-cluster (Supports only one database. Better if you have a big dataset)

So in that case, type 2 will not met my requirements as I need to have 50 pod of redis , 25 on node1, and other 25 on the node2, and each of them has their own persistent volume, can you please explain more ?

Comment: So the whole idea of containers is to scale them dynamically. I do not get it why you want to have exactly 50 pods as that could be managed by a scaling group if you have a lot of traffic. Could you tell sth more about where you are deploying it and what is your target architecture?

Comment: Thanks Armando for your prompt, my goal is to divide the number of users between the redis nodes, for example user 1..1000 will be available in redis01, users 1001..2000 in redis02 and so on, so the app could be dynamically scaled, but for the redis I need name and port to be different as well as the volume of each redis, so somehow I need the redis nodes to be not scaled dynamicaly but fixed.

Comment: I see what you mean...I guess your approach would have considerable scalability issues although I do not fully know what you are trying to acheave. Sharding is now considered an antipattern. There can be many other better ways to solve your problem that favour scalability, high availability and consistency not to mention maintainability and evloution of your application. I could also be wrong so dont take my word on that. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

as mention in above answer, you can definitely use the helm chart however you can also use the operator in Kubernetes.

Redis operator : https://github.com/spotahome/redis-operator

The operator gives you extra functionality and manages Redis cluster.

in Kubernetes you can use HA helm redis chart and scale it with stateful sets which is backed by PVC.

PVC knows as persistence volume claim which will be storing redis `.rdb` snapshot and `.aof` `appendonly` file.